# Identifying if RAID is used or not

Tags: linux, raid

I have a Linux server, and when I want to see its hard disk size,
I use this command: `df -h`

But in fact, I know, my server consists of some hard disks and its original disk space is more than that. 
There may be RAID. 
My question is this:
How can I know (identify) if RAID is used or not in server and see original hard disk size?

Comment: Well /proc/mdstat will give you information about whether RAID is in use or not.

Comment: I saw in in server and it gives: unused devices: none. What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four possible places RAID might be configured on a Linux system:

1. At the hardware level.  In other words, you have an actual physical RAID controller in your system.  There's no easy 100% reliable way to check this from software, but running `lspci` should list it if you have one (though I'm not 100% certain *how* it will be listed).
2. At the firmware level.  This is rare on server systems, because it's generally less efficient than having it at the hardware level and less flexible than having it in the block layer.  The 'RAID' mode in most Intel and AMD SATA controllers is an example of this.  I have absolutely zero advice for how to check this, as I avoid using it at all costs (performance is usually mediocre at best, and Linux support for configuration is essentially non-existent).
3. In the block layer.  This is RAID done using either MD or LVM.  Checking is pretty easy.  If `/proc/mdstat` lists any devices, you've got MD RAID configured on your system.  If `lvs -a` lists any devices, you might have LVM-based RAID on your system (If the 'Attrs' column shows anything that starts with an `r` in the first spot, you have at least one volume with either replication (RAID1 or RAID10) or erasure coding (RAID5 or RAID6).  There is no easy way to check for striped volumes).
4. In the filesystem.  This can be the case if you are using either ZFS or BTRFS for your filesystem.  For ZFS, I'm not quite sure how to check what replication/striping/parity is being used.  For BTRFS, run `btrfs filesystem show` and see if you have any volumes that list more than one device (such volumes should be treated like RAID for what you care about here).

Now, as to figuring out how big the disks are, you are correct that `df` won't show you the info you want.  It just displays the usage for each mounted filesystem, which is not the same as displaying the size of each disk.

In the event that you can directly access the underlying devices (always the case for cases 3 and 4 above, and usually the case for cases 1 and 2), you can directly query the size of the disk by running `blockdev --getsize64` on the device, which will print out the exact usable size of the device in kilobytes.

If you can't directly access the underlying devices (which is a possibility for cases 1 and 2 above), you will have to look at them through the configuration tools for whatever RAID controller you have.

Of course, the most reliable way to figure out the hard disk size is to just ignore all the software involved, open up the case, and look at the hard drive itself.  All modern drives have their capacity listed on the label.

Comment: `lshw` should show a hardware RAID controller, and possibly which disks are attached to it, and possibly the single "disk" it presents to the OS, etc.

Comment: @ivanivan I forgot about `lshw`, probably because I rarely use it myself (when I need info that detailed, I usually just open up the case and look at the labels on stuff).

Comment: no problem, just wanted to add the extra. `lshw` is such a nice utility, especially if you do something like `sudo lswh -html > ~/Desktop/my_hardware.html`  - color codign tells you which devices are claimed by a driver, etc.